# Execute commands in background

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, exec

I am implementing a minishell that will emulate a real bash shell. I am stacked with the execution of commands in background such as `ls &`.

My first approach was the following (which does not work)

```
char *execArgs[] = { "ls", "&", NULL };
execvp("ls", execArgs);
```

Then, I tried another way by modifying the parent process of the `fork()` and not waiting for the child in case it should be run in background. The problem here is that then it should print the list of jobs running on background in order to simulate the background bahaviour in a bash shell, but the command `jobs` is not executed correctly as a parameter of `execvp()`.

My question is, is there any easier way to implement this background calls in C? In case there isn't, what does it fail in either of the options that I have mentioned?

Comment: There is a better way, use [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

Comment: In order your `jobs` command to execute properly, you have to implement it properly. For example by tracking all of the forked "background" processes.

Comment: Im currently using for(). What benefict will I gain regarding the background process execution if I track all of them?

Comment: The benefit of knowing about them in order to list them when executing `jobs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons your example fails is

- The "&" as you have it coded is an argument to the "ls" program.  When you enter the command at a shell prompt, the "&" is consumed by the shell and the "ls" program never see the backgrounding.
- The "exec()" call terminates the current program (i.e., your mini-shell).

What you may want is

```
system("ls &");
```

Read a good Unix book.  You will need to know fork(), exec(), wait() and more.

Comment: Note that running `system("ls &")` will delegate backgrounding to `/bin/sh`, but further job control will not be available.